# Need Help Getting Code to Loop though website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I get this code to go through all 430 pages of the website and output to a file?

```
>>> import requests, bs4
>>> resp = requests.get('https://everythingrs.com/tools/osrs/itemlist')
>>> bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.content)
>>> [(tr.find('strong').text, tr.find('td', class_='alt1').text) for tr in bs.find_all('tr')[1:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the website you are scrapping the pages are identified by url + pagenumber so to get all 430 pages use just need to make a for loop to loop through all pages i.e

`for page_no in range(1,431):
    resp = requests.get('https://everythingrs.com/tools/osrs/itemlist' + str(page_no))
    // All the rest of the code here`

To save the output into a file you can use `open(filename)`

`with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    for i in output_array:
       f.write(i[0]);
       f.write(i[1]);`

Modify the above code in the format that you want. You can also use `requests.session` to increase download speed.